# xslt concatenations

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml data

```
<XMLCreators>
<row>
<RateNumber>1</RateNumber>
<RateLetter>Null</RateLetter>
<AssessmentStreet>Abesinia Passage</AssessmentStreet>
<RateAccomDesc>Dwelling  (Part Of)</RateAccomDesc>
</row>
<row>
<RateNumber>1a</RateNumber>
<RateLetter>Null</RateLetter>
<AssessmentStreet>Arena's Palace Lane</AssessmentStreet>
<RateAccomDesc>Edmund's Home</RateAccomDesc>
</row>
</XMLCreators>
```

I changed its output element with this xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Address>  <xsl:apply-templates/> </Address>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/XMLCreators/row">
    <Rowinfo> <xsl:apply-templates/> </Rowinfo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/XMLCreators/row/RateNumber">
    <Locator> <xsl:apply-templates/> </Locator>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/XMLCreators/row/AssessmentStreet">
    <thoroughfare> <xsl:apply-templates/> </thoroughfare>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/XMLCreators/row/RateAccomDesc">
    <LocatorName> <xsl:apply-templates/> </LocatorName>
</xsl:template>

     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and produced this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Address>
<Rowinfo>
<Locator>1</Locator>
Null
<thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
<LocatorName>Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorName>
</Rowinfo>
<Rowinfo>
<Locator>1a</Locator>
Null
<thoroughfare>Arena's Palace Lane</thoroughfare>
<LocatorName>Edmund's Home</LocatorName>
</Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

I want to add a new element to the rowinfo (locatordesignator) and populate it with the concatenation of the values of (rateletter and RateAccomDesc).

Please, I need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just add this template**:

```
 <xsl:template match="RateLetter">
  <LocatorDesignator>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ', ', ../RateAccomDesc)"/>
  </LocatorDesignator>
 </xsl:template>
```

**The complete transformation now becomes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Address>  <xsl:apply-templates/> </Address>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row">
  <Rowinfo> <xsl:apply-templates/> </Rowinfo>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="RateNumber">
  <Locator> <xsl:apply-templates/> </Locator>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="AssessmentStreet">
  <thoroughfare> <xsl:apply-templates/> </thoroughfare>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="RateAccomDesc">
  <LocatorName> <xsl:apply-templates/> </LocatorName>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="RateLetter">
  <LocatorDesignator>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ', ', ../RateAccomDesc)"/>
  </LocatorDesignator>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when it is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<XMLCreators>
    <row>
        <RateNumber>1</RateNumber>
        <RateLetter>Null</RateLetter>
        <AssessmentStreet>Abesinia Passage</AssessmentStreet>
        <RateAccomDesc>Dwelling  (Part Of)</RateAccomDesc>
    </row>
    <row>
        <RateNumber>1a</RateNumber>
        <RateLetter>Null</RateLetter>
        <AssessmentStreet>Arena's Palace Lane</AssessmentStreet>
        <RateAccomDesc>Edmund's Home</RateAccomDesc>
    </row>
</XMLCreators>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Address>
   <Rowinfo>
      <Locator>1</Locator>
      <LocatorDesignator>Null, Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorDesignator>
      <thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
      <LocatorName>Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorName>
   </Rowinfo>
   <Rowinfo>
      <Locator>1a</Locator>
      <LocatorDesignator>Null, Edmund's Home</LocatorDesignator>
      <thoroughfare>Arena's Palace Lane</thoroughfare>
      <LocatorName>Edmund's Home</LocatorName>
   </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of templates and the Standard XPath **[`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat)** function.

Comment: Thanx alot!!!!! however if you want the RateAccomDesc to come before the rateletter?

Comment: I used this <xsl:value-of select="concat(../RateAccomDesc,', ',.)"/>

Comment: Please, How do i arrange the output in this order  Locator designator,
Locator name,
Locator,
Thoroughfare
Addressarea.

Comment: @lee, Please, ask this as a new question -- re-ordering of elements. This can be done as a second pass applied on the results of the current transformation (more understandable and maintainable), or it can be done by modifying the transformation and implicitly sequencing a number of `xsl:apply-templates` instructions with the specific `select` attribute valuues wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the additional information to one of your templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/XMLCreators/row">
    <Rowinfo>
        <locatordesignator>
            <xsl:value-of select="RateLetter"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="RateAccomDesc"/>
        </locatordesignator>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Rowinfo>
</xsl:template>
```